# Pushing a navigation controller from a UIView subclass leads to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView subclass which has to push a viewController onto the navigation stack if a button in it is tapped. So I keep a copy of the navigation controller in my appDelegate. Then I do the following from the button's action method:

```
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

This causes the app to crash when nextViewController is popped. This is fixed when I follow the more standard method of posting a notification from the UIView subclass, recieving it in the parent view controller and pushing nextViewController from there.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

tried this code....

Comment: I am in a UIView subclass where self has no navigation controller.

Comment: No, I have declared as a property.